# Can I open “data.xyz” file in Internet Explorer on Windows Phone

Tags: internet-explorer

I can not find a way to "send to..." or "open with..." file with extension "xyz" with IE on Windows Phone. Can it be done and if yes, does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: What data type is ".xyz"? If it's not supported by Windows Phone natively you'll need an app that can handle this file.

Answer (score 1):

When you download files, you will get a prompt to choose to download or open, when there is an app installed associated to the MIME type of the file. For other files, or when you choose to save, these are stored in the Downloads folder that shows up when you connect to your PC, or in the Files app.

Comment: And what if no MIME type exist for that file ?

Comment: On desktop is easy, "send to..." or shellexecute (C/API) with file name as OPEN target. On Windows Phone there is no such a thing.

Comment: There will always be a MIME type sent by the download server (hopefully one that matches actual type of the file). You can also open from the Files app, which will prompt to search the store if a suitable app is not installed

Comment: So, they created OS that I HAVE NO control of who is running what, nor I can enforce it ?
Do they know what is that for business type of applications ?
Well, no wonder than:
"bringing down its market share in the U.S. from 3.6% to 3.0% in just one quarter"
(source: http://www.ubergizmo.com/2015/06/windows-phone-market-share-in-the-u-s-drops-significantly/)...                                 .well, stick to our Android solution....

Comment: You have control over the apps you choose to install/use - for example, there are multiple PDF readers in the store.

Comment: Agree, but in my scenario: (1) application create image representing current data in chart  (2) save that "image" with extension 'xyz' to avoid image showing in user 'gallery'   (3) lunching image viewer application passing file.xyz as input => image is displayed to the user.                To bad I can not do that on MS Phone OS....What were they thinking when designing the OS ?

Comment: So you're not actually dealing with a file downloaded from a website, and this is a development question for an app you're writing?

Comment: ...and I see you've asked the same question on the site for development questions (where I've added a comment referring the relevant documentation, and flagged the question for reopening)